# Snooze Alarm in Alarm Clock Application in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification, mpmediaitemcollection

I've been working on Alarm Clock application and using local notifications to pop the alarm.
I also need to snooze the alarm as per the time interval set by the user in user settings.

The user cannot snooze until the application starts i.e below mentioned method is called.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

As I'm calling the method to snooze alarm by adding the time interval in firedate and rescheduling the local notification.

The problem is the application comes to foreground and according to Apple's HIG I should not terminate the app or send the app to background automatically and hence user needs to press home button to send the app in background.

Recently, I came across [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarm-clock-free/id332064280?mt=8). It can snooze the alarm the way I want to.

One more issue is I can select sound to be played from My Music Library in [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarm-clock-free/id332064280?mt=8).

Any idea how this app manages to do so?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you are after there are several things to consider. Your approach of using `UILocalNotification` is correct so that is a good start.

In order implement a 'snooze' feature properly you will need to consider the app running in both the foreground and the background.

- If the app is in the foreground (or the user opens the app from the notification banner from outside) `application:didReceieveLocalNotification:` will be called and you can simply update your UI to show a snooze button and schedule a new local notification from the duration loaded from NSUserDefaults.
- If the app is the in background and the user closes the notification then there is no way to subsequently try and 'snooze' the alarm.

As for playing a custom sound from the iTunes library take a look at the `soundName` property on [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks Dan, I'm already checking for the app status i.e. if app is in foreground I can do anything I want to do like displaying alertview, playing sound etc. The problem is what to do when app is in background? As I've seen in the app I mentioned is snoozing in background. Is it possible that the app is using Push Notification instead of local notification?

Comment: For soundname property of local notification: Apple says the sound file should not be of more then 30 sec. The files in iTunes Library can be greater than 30 sec, I've tried getting file path from media controller and set it as a soundname, but it didn't worked. I guess its because iTunes file is greater than 30 sec. Or probably I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Yes I would say they are using push notifications and controlling the alarms via a web service in the cloud. That way if the notifications are not cleared they can push another one x minute later and "snooze". Does that make sense?